# How to query with japanese in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a problem with querying in Japanese, what should I do?

```sql
SELECT current_date() AS 時間;
```

**Error**

> Invalid field name "時間". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 300 characters long.

[image: jp]

[image: jp2]

Comment: Did you have a chance to check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69319435/13171940)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently table names and column names are English-only.
As stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names):

> A column name must contain only letters (a-z, A-Z), numbers (0-9), or
> underscores (_), and it must start with a letter or underscore. The
> maximum column name length is 300 characters. A column name cannot use
> any of the following prefixes: *TABLE*, *FILE*, *PARTITION*. Duplicate
> column names are not allowed even if the case differs. For example, a
> column named Column1 is considered identical to a column named
> column1.

Therefore, other characters including japanese cannot be used as column names.

More info: https://issuetracker.google.com/65034056